# Import Angular Material theme in Nrwl Nx libs

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl

I have a [nrwl nx](https://nrwl.io/nx) workspace with apps and libs.

In one of my libs I want to import an angular material theme, but in browser I get the following warning:

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

I have imported the following line in my `list.component.scss`:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Actually, what I want was to import this in a `styles.scss`, but `styles.scss` is not available in `libs` and if I add one I don't know where to reference it.

Comment: There are couple of ways you could achieve this with.

Answer (score 1):

Without any issues I'm importing Angular Material into Nx using `ng add @angular/material`, remember to have in `angular.json` the setup

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
]
```

Comment: Where exactly i need to put this in angular.json?

Comment: ‘styles’ in ‘angular.json’, as written.

Comment: @DanielDanielecki The nx with MFA workspace doesn't have an angular.json file. Where do we put on MFA application

Comment: @SanJaisy, I'm afraid, I can't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the theming in the app specific style.css?

This is what I have in my setup. I have a library which contains Login.component. the template is using the material components. I added the style import in the app style.css which imports this library to use login component. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

@DAG
I have done something similar with one of my project. These are few things that I did.

(If you haven't already  then install it with `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`)

Once you have material design installed and available in node_modules
For this example we have workspace name `demo` and style file name `demo-styles.scss` and lib name `my-lib`

1. create a new lib into your workspace using `ng g lib demoLib` and follow along with command line guide and select **no** for creating module inside lib.
2. This will get you a library with src directory which has nothing in it.
3. Next, you can go ahead and add new directory named `styles` under `src`
   directory. Once you have done this you can add different style files inside `styles` directory.
4. Update tsconfig to reference your new styles folder.

   {
     {
       "compilerOptions": {
        "path": {
          "@demo/my-liib/`*`": ["libs/my-lib/src/styles/`*`"]
        }
     }
   }
5. Once you have done this,

   - you can import this lib in `app/styles.scss` with

     `@import demo/my-lib/styles/demo-styles.scss`.

Now you will be able to work with  styles defined in stylefile.scss.
Hope this helps.

Comment: IMPORTANT: you will also need to add `"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "libs/my-lib/src/"
              ]
            }` inside build option of your app.

Answer (score -1):

Get inspired by the `@angular/material` library itself, and how they provide the `_theming.scss` file which is built with `sass-bundler` (if I remember correctly).

Once I did that in one of my libs, and I had to consume its styles just in the way you have to do it with Material itself, for following projects I just opted to have those styles in the global styles of my App, as I wasn't publishing the lib anyways.